# Redux performance in long arrays of coordinates. I need to get all the coordinates on a huge array to show in a map

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm having an issue and I would love your help! I'm tracking a car trip using a library (https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation) then I'm storing each second the current position status in redux state. This makes a really huge array of objects (thousands) with data like coordinates, speed, altitude.. etc... and this makes an issue with performance (slow tracking current position)... I need to show coordinates in map in order to know all the ride trip while he is in it... Do you think I need to store it outside redux state?

Answer (score 4):

The question is how you handle the data today. If you are using immutability (as redux expect) then I'd suggest that you would use the [Immutable.js](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-immutablejs-with-redux/) library or similar. Otherwise every change will mean that you have to change the full array. Immutable.js is smart this way as it allows you to change it, without it actually changing more than necessary (behind the scenes).

Secondly, make sure you are creating [pure components](https://www.fullstackreact.com/30-days-of-react/day-11/) and that the component read its coordinates directly from the store and not as a passed property from the parent (to avoid unnecessary redraws).

Another suggestion would be to make each trip-segment a react component on its own, knowing two datapoints in your set only. Then that react-component would only update if the co-ordinates changes (which will be never, given that none of the datapoints are meant to be changed afterwards).

There may not be a "perfect answer" to your question, not without seeing your code. With the information you have provided I think that the suggestions above should give you some options for improving the performance.

Comment: I  believe Using Immutable.Js  in redux is an Optimize Way .  Good Suggestion . https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks. Please upvote and/or mark as answer if this answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to store it outside the redux, but also you can sync the data with your backend and remove the synced data from redux.
But if you have an offline-first application you can use local databases.

Two good choices are:

SQLite: `https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage`

and

Couchbase Lite: `https://github.com/couchbaselabs/react-native-couchbase-lite`

They both give you query options too which would be good for visualization query.